# RegExp pattern for a String which contain 0 and 4-9(4 ,5,6,7,8,9)

Tags: java, regex

I am dealing with a string. Use-Case is I don't want a String which has number any digit of 4 to 9 and 0.

Example:-

```
ABC0123-> Not Valid.
XYZ002456789->Not Valid.
ABC123->Valid
ABC1->Valid
```

I have tried below pattern but not got success in it.

```
String pattern = "^[0,4-9]+$"; 
if(str.matches(pattern)){
      //do something.
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, remove the comma from the character class. You're not looking for commas.

Since you're *disallowing*, don't anchor the expression, allow the match anywhere in the string. In fact, `matches` anchors the expression for you, so we have to intentionally allow characters before and after the disallowed character class:

```
String pattern = ".*[04-9].*";
if(str.matches(pattern)){
      // disallow
}
```

[Live Example](https://ideone.com/PFQW8q)

Alternately, you can avoid having those `.*` in there by using `Pattern.compile` and then using the resulting `Pattern` instead of `matches`, since it won't automatically anchor the pattern like `matches` does.

Answer (score 1):

It is much more easier to match those that contains 4-9 and 0 than to match those that don't. So you should just write a regex like this:

```
[4-90]
```

And call `find`, then invert the result:

```
if (!Pattern.compile("[4-90]").matcher(someString).find()) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to use a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and add what you don't want to match. In this case you could add 0 and a range from 4-9 and if you don't want to match a carriage return or a newline you could add those as well.

`^[^04-9\\r\\n]+$`

Note that if you add the comma to the character class that it would mean a comma literally.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Nb1wgW/1) | [Java demo](https://rextester.com/HNBFT22748)

```
String pattern = "^[^04-9\\r\\n]+$";
if(str.matches(pattern)){
    //do something.
}
```

Comment: Thanks "The fourth Bird" for answer.